# display pricing information outside Salesforce

Tags: integration

We have a Salesforce integration within our application where users can access their Salesforce account using SAML SSO & JIT user provisioning. We also display few account & user details. We want to display Salesforce pricing information (the amount to be paid to Salesforce.com for subscription, due date etc). from where and how to fetch this data for any particular account?

Comment: We display Account / User / contact info using SOAP API from Salesforce Object. But I cannot see any object where billing information is stored.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense to me. You allow users to access their own account (do you mean the account sobject or an org) and want to show pricing that they pay to salesforce.com? Why would salesforce.com ever put the license price in an org or user record?
Please restate the question, being careful to separate the word "account" into User, Org, Account, etc, as you used the same word for too many things.

Answer (score 0):

Your org account information is accessible via [the Your Account app](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_checkout.htm&type=5). You can give your billing users access to this app via the Your Account App Admin User permission set.

You can access the app via the Setup icon:

[image: Setup]

As of the latest [Object Reference for Salesforce Platform](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) API version at the time of this post (v. 60.0), the objects utilized in the Your Account App are unavailable for use. Consequently, you will be unable to expose the data to external systems or customize them within the Salesforce platform.